# Toggle the display of options in a Select

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am creating a web page which will have a Select element with a number of Options. Each option represents two values: a code and a human-readable string. I would like to allow the user to toggle a setting (on the same page) which would dynamically toggle the select so that just the code or the human-readable string is visible.

I have thought of a couple of ways of doing this:

1. When the toggle is pressed, I re-create the page and the appropriate Options are loaded into the Select. This has the disadvantage of clearing all of the other fields on the page.
2. Having 2 Selects where 1 is always hidden. One Select has options with codes. The other Select has options with human-readable strings. The toggle would hide / show the appropriate Select. This has the disadvantage in that I have to manually keep the 2 Selects in sync.

Also note there will be a number of Selects that need to be toggled on any one page.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use option title to hold second string and swap it on toggle with option.innerHTML

```
<option title="human-readable string">short</option>
```

swap to

```
<option title="short">human-readable string</option>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify?  Are you suggesting writing a piece of Javascript which would walk all of the options in a Select and for each option, swap the title with the innerHTML ?

Comment: yes, if you are using jQuery it looks like: $('option.needSwap').each(function(){ var sw = this.innerHTML; this.innerHtml = this.title; this.title = sw;}); Where needSwap is a className of the option that need to be swapped on toggle;

Comment: Sorry, quick syntax issue check: Using JQuery if my Select is called foo, do I refer to the options like the following:  $('#foo').options.each(

Comment: $('option', $('#foo')).each( ...; or $('$#foo option').each(...; or $('#foo').find('option').each(...;

Comment: FYI: http://jsperf.com/give-context-vs-not/2 selectors performance tests; you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I say it depends on the datasize your selects will be holding. If it's a big chunk you are better served with a kind of your first idea.
Are your selects dynamically growing (like user adding options and so on)? If yes i would go the AJAXian way and do kind of the second idea.

Comment: Nope. Small entries. However, the codelists are short (e.g. 123) but the human-readable strings could be long (e.g. "The total sum of all of the farm animals of Outer Mongolia")

Comment: Well Irishka got a pretty solid idea with holding one value in the title-attribute and the other is in the innerHTML-part. 
The question here is, if a select field is really what you need.